# Unable to catch thrown exception

Tags: java

There are two classes A and C both containing static blocks, but only A.java has a main method. I want to call C from A ie dynamically load it using forName(). Since C does not have a .class file I get a ClassnotFoundException that I catch at main using throws clause, but I find that it does not get caught. Need help figuring out what I am doing wrong:

```
class  A
{  
    static 
    {
        System.out.println("A class static block");
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
     {
          Class.forName( "C" ); 
     }
}


class C 
{
    static 
    {
        System.out.println("C class static block");
    }
}
```

Output is as follows:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\MyJavaPrograms\MyJava>java A
A class static block
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at A.main(A.java:10)
```

Comment: You are throw the exception in `main` then it throw exception. What are you expected? If you want to catch it the using a `try/catch` block instead of throw it

Comment: What does it mean to throw something in Java?
Throws clause is used to declare the exceptions that are not handled by a particular method and is an instruction to the callers to either handle these explicitly or rethrow them up in the call hierarchy. ... The throws keyword indicates that a certain method can potentially "throw" a certain exception.

Comment: So I am expecting main to throw and exception and I am handling it using the throws clause or atleast that is what I think. I am still learning java.

Comment: I am expecting the following output

Comment: A class static block   C class static block

Comment: As I already said. You want to handle the exception then using `try/catch` block to catch and handle it. You must learn again about handle exception. Here is a [post for you can refer](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-exception-handling/)

Comment: I am unable to use newline in this comment box hence above outputs shown in same line. Actually they are on different line

Comment: *I get a ClassnotFoundException that I catch at main using throws clause* - that's not how exception handling works. Catching is the opposite of throwing.

Comment: Don't worry, we all started as beginners and got confused by such stuff. I recommend you to grab a good learning resource where you can look up all topics, concepts and elements of the Java language.

Comment: @Zabuza Talking to me?

Comment: No sorry, meant @Mona

Answer (score 1):

> I get a ClassnotFoundException that I catch at main using throws clause

Actually, a `throws` clause does the opposite of catching an exception--it tells the compiler that you expect the exception to be thrown by this method if anything inside of it throws the exception. Catching looks like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      Class.forName( "C" ); 
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      // add logging code or something here.
    }
  }
```

Comment: Oh ok, maybe I got it all wrong then. I was actually running code as shown in a video. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Since C does not have a .class file I get a ClassnotFoundException that I catch at main using throws clause

But in your code you actually do **not** catch the `ClassNotFoundException`. The **try-catch** concept works by surrounding the code block that is expected to throw the exception with a **try-block** and then you are able to add a corresponding **catch-block** to specifiy what to do if that exception occurred in the **try-block**. You do so like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        Class.forName("C"); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("The class was not found.");
    }
}
```

If the exception occurs inside the **try-block** then it will abort the computation inside the block and directly jump to the **catch-block**. After the **catch-block** has been executed it will regularly continue with the code outside of the **try-catch** construct.

---

What you did with your

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
```

just means "*Hey, if you want to use that method, note that it could throw this exception*". It is a hint for a caller of that method to proper handle the error case.

Also if that specified `Exception` is a so called **checked exception** then the caller **must** handle the error case, either by also specifying *throws XYException* (which means: "*I do not handle the error, I let the caller of my method do it...*") or catching it with **try-catch** like seen above.

The `ClassNotFoundException` is such a **checked exception**. All exceptions except the one extending from `RuntimeException` are **checked** and need to be handled when using such a method. Other examples would be `IOException` or `FileNotFoundException`. An example for an **unchecked exception** would be `IllegalArgumentException` or `ArithmeticException` if you try to divide by zero like in `5 / 0`.

---

You can read more about the topic and everything **try-catch** has to offer (multi-catch, finally-block, ...) in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).